# How do I map a position in a n dimensional matrix to 1D, in C++ at compile time?

Tags: templates, matrix, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have to calculate the position of an element in a `n` dimensional matrix, inside a 1D array, during compile time.
In short terms, a mapping of `array[i][j][k]....[n] -> array[...]`, where `i,j,k,...,n` in `{1,2,3}` and the dimension of every index is `DIM = 3`. That means, every row and column has 3 elements.

My main problem is to write the summation for `n` indices (parameter pack), as template and using `constexpr` to evaluate the sum at compile time.

My research in other stack post resulted in the following formula for 3 dimension:

```
    a[i][j][k] -> a[(i*DIM*DIM) + (j*DIM) + k]
```

If we expand it to `n` dimensions, it results in the following formula:

```
    a[i][j][k]....[n] -> a[(n*DIM ^ (indexAmount-1)] +... + (i*DIM*DIM) + (j*DIM) + k].
```

Furthermore, `i` wrote the code to generate the addends of the sum using templates and `constexpr`, which is shown in the code below.

```
    /**
    * calculates DIM3^(indexPos)
    */
    template<auto count>
    int constexpr multiple_dim(){
        if constexpr (count == 0){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return DIM3 * multiple_dim<count-1>();
        }
    }

    /**
    *
    *calculates addends for the end summation
    * e.g if we have 3 indices i,j,k. j would be at position 2
    * and j = 1. The parameters would be IndexPos = 2, index = 1.

    */
    template<auto indexPos, auto index>
    int constexpr calculate_flattened_index(){
        if constexpr (indexPos == 0){
            return (index-1);
        }else{
            return (index-1) * multiple_dim<indexPos>();
        }
    }

    /**
     * calculates the position of an element inside a
     * nD matrix and maps it to a position in 1D
     * A[i][j]..[n] -> ???? not implemented yet
     * @tparam Args
     * @return
     */
    template<auto ...Args>
    [[maybe_unused]] auto constexpr pos_nd_to_1d(){
     /* maybe iterate over all indices inside the parameter pack?
        const int count = 1;
        for(int x : {Args...}){

        }
        return count;
    */
    }
```

An example output for the elements inside a 3D Matrix `A`.
`A111`, `A121`, `A131`. The sum over the 3 elements would be the position in 1D. For e.g `A121 -> 0 + 3 + 0 = 3`. `A111` would be placed in a 1 dimensional array at `array[3]`.

```
    std::cout << "Matrix A111" << std::endl;
    //A111
    std::cout << calculate_flattened_index<0 , 1>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << calculate_flattened_index<1 , 1>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << calculate_flattened_index<2 , 1>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Matrix A121" << std::endl;
    //A121
    std::cout << calculate_flattened_index<0 , 1>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << calculate_flattened_index<1 , 2>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << calculate_flattened_index<2 , 1>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Matrix A131" << std::endl;
    //A131
    std::cout << calculate_flattened_index<0 , 1>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << calculate_flattened_index<1 , 3>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << calculate_flattened_index<2 , 1>() << std::endl;

    Output:
    Matrix A111
    0
    0
    0
    Matrix A121
    0
    3
    0
    Matrix A131
    0
    6
    0
```

An desired output could look like the following code:

Function call

```
    pos_nd_to_1d<1,1,1>() //A111 
    pos_nd_to_1d<1,2,1>() //A121 
    pos_nd_to_1d<1,3,1>() //A131
```

Output:

```
    0 //0+0+0
    3 //0+3+0
    6 //0+6+0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly... your looking something as follows

```
template <auto ... as>
auto constexpr pos_nd_to_1d ()
 { 
   std::size_t  i { 0u };

   ((i *= DIM, i += as - 1u), ...);

   return i;
 }
```

Or maybe you can use `std::common_type`, for `i`,

```
std::common_type_t<decltype(as)...>  i {};
```

but for indices I suggest the use of `std::size_t` (also `std::size_t ... as`).

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto DIM = 3u;

template <auto ... as>
auto constexpr pos_nd_to_1d ()
 { 
   std::size_t  i { 0u };

   ((i *= DIM, i += as - 1u), ...);

   return i;
 }


int main ()
 {
   std::cout << pos_nd_to_1d<1u, 1u, 1u>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << pos_nd_to_1d<1u, 2u, 1u>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << pos_nd_to_1d<1u, 3u, 1u>() << std::endl;
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> could you explain how this code works?I am a bit new to c++.

I'm better at coding that at explaining, anyway...

What I've used here

```
   ((i *= DIM, i += as - 1u), ...);
//...^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   repeated part
```

is called "[fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)" (or also "folding" or "template folding"), and is a new C++17 feature (you can obtain the same result also in C++14 (also C++11 but not `constexpr`) but in a less simple and elegant way) that consist in expanding a variadic template pack with an operator.

By example, if you want to sum the indexes, you can simply write

```
(as + ...);
```

and the expression become

```
(a0 + (a1 + (a2 + (/* etc */))));
```

In this case I've used the fact that the comma is an operator, so the expression

```
   ((i *= DIM, i += as - 1u), ...);
```

become

```
   ((i *= DIM, i += a0 - 1u), 
     ((i *= DIM, i += a1 - 1u),
        ((i *= DIM, i += a2 - 1u),
           /* etc. */ )))))
```

Observe that, this way, the first `i *= DIM` is unuseful (because `i` is initialized with zero) but the following `i *= DIM` multiply `as - 1u` the right number of times

So, when `as...` is `1, 2, 1`, by example, you get

```
  (1 - 1)*DIM*DIM + (2 - 1)*DIM + (1 - 1)
```

Comment: if you have some spare time, could you explain how this code works?I am a bit new to c++.

Comment: @M.Mac - answer improved; hope this helps.